# How to find the number of vowels in a string?

Tags: python

We want to know the index of the vowels in a given word, for example, there are two vowels in the word super (the second and fourth letters).

So given a string "super", we should return a list of [2, 4].

My Code:

```
def vowel_indices(word):
    global vowels
    global vowelsList
    vowels = ["a" , "e" , "i" , "o" , "u" , "A" , "E" , "I" , "O" , "U"]
    vowelsList = []
    for letter in word:
        if letter in vowels:
            vowelsList.append(letter)
            print(len(vowelsList))

vowel_indices("Anthony")
```

Instead of getting: 2, I'm getting: 1 2

Comment: And I want people to stop spamming tags

Comment: You should clean up the indentation of your code: this is critical in Python. Also, your variables `vowels` and `vowelsList` are not actually global variables, and I see no reason to have the latter as one or to declare the former as one. Please show us code that basically works, and see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You are printing every time you see a vowel.

Comment: Make the effort to complete the 2-minute site tour.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to return the indices of the vowels, than you should `enumerate` the word.

```
vowelsList = [idx for idx, letter in enumerate(word) if letter in vowels]
```

[Live example](https://ideone.com/jkGvzK)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
>>> import re
>>> def vowel_indices(word):
>>>   return len(re.findall('[aeiou]', word, re.IGNORECASE));
>>> print(vowel_indices("Anthony"));
2
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your question's title, to find the number of vowels in a word, try the following:

```
len([l for l in word if l in 'aeiouAEIOU'])
```

In a function, it would be:

```
def vowels_number(word):
    return len([l for l in word if l in 'aeiouAEIOU'])
```

**Example of output:**

```
>>> vowels_number('hello')
2
>>>
>>> vowels_number('world')
1
>>> 
>>> vowels_number("Anthony")
2
```

To make your code works, this is what you can try:

```
vowels = 'aeiouAEIOU'

def vowels_number(word):
    vowels_list = []
    for letter in word:
        if letter in vowels:
            vowels_list.append(letter)
    return len(vowels_list)
```

**Output:**

```
>>> vowels_number("Anthony")
2
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is almost okay just two things you got wrong.See below:

```
  def vowel_indices(word):
        global vowels
        global vowelsList
        vowels = ["a" , "e" , "i" , "o" , "u" , "A" , "E" , "I" , "O" , "U"]
        vowelsList = []
        for index,letter in enumerate(word):#add an index with enumerate 
            if letter in vowels:
                vowelsList.append(index+1)#add 1 since list/arrays starts from 0
        print(vowelsList)

    vowel_indices("Super")
    vowel_indices("anthony")
```

Output:

```
[2, 4]
[1, 5]
```